# Can not import some Education from Linkedin

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have marked with a cross, that were not imported. I think this is because of comma before title.

[image: Can not import from Linkedin]

Answer (score 2):

So the best fix for this is to populate the 'Degree' section in LinkedIn and try the import again, but for the situation where you don't populate it we now substitute 'Other' (or the localized form of 'Other') instead.

Thanks for the report! :)